# SSL handshake with ActiveMQ server gives NullPointerException when connecting via SilverTunnel netlib

Tags: ssl, nullpointerexception, activemq-classic, freeze, handshake

### Summary

Connecting to ActiveMQ via TCP works fine with or without netlib.
Connecting via **SSL** works fine without netlib **but fails with netlib**.

Note: I'm using **apache-activemq-5.6.0** and **silvertunnel.org_netlib-0.14-beta**.

This problem occurs whether using netlib's tcpipNetLayer or torNetLayer. However, only the tcpipNetLayer case is considered here to keep things simple.

BTW, SSL + netlib worked fine with the HornetQ messaging server (which implements SSL authentication differently) but HornetQ had problems that led me to try using ActiveMQ.

For convenience I have created a [simple test case](http://anandavala.info/miscl/testing-AMQ-Netlib-SSL.zip) with a **consumer** and two different producers.

- **producer** connects without netlib - works fine.
- **producer-tcpip** connects with neltib using the tcpipNetLayer - the following errors occur:

With SSL debugging turned on for ActiveMQ the producer-tcpip program outputs to the console the following error message and then hangs:

```
ActiveMQ Transport: ssl://null:0, handling exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is midway through an SSL handshake because the producer-tcpip program generates the log4j message:

```
DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Attempting  0th  connect to: ssl://localhost:61616
DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator - Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=9, properties={MaxFrameSize=104857600, CacheSize=1024, CacheEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, TightEncodingEnabled=true, StackTraceEnabled=true}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
```

Then when the producer-tcpip program is killed (e.g. with a ctrl+C) then the activemq.log reports that:

```
WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:49463 failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: ssl:///127.0.0.1:49463
ERROR | Could not accept connection from tcp://127.0.0.1:49463: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ Task-3
```

I have no idea what could be causing this or how it can be resolved. Can anyone help?

### Steps to reproduce the problem (takes under 15 minutes):

download the [test case](http://anandavala.info/miscl/testing-AMQ-Netlib-SSL.zip)

```
wget http://anandavala.info/miscl/testing-AMQ-Netlib-SSL.zip
unzip testing-AMQ-Netlib-SSL.zip
rm testing-AMQ-Netlib-SSL.zip
cd testing-AMQ-Netlib-SSL
```

Download latest ActiveMQ into the testing directory

```
wget https://www.apache.org/dist/activemq/apache-activemq/5.6.0/apache-activemq-5.6.0-bin.tar.gz
tar -xzf apache-activemq-5.6.0-bin.tar.gz
rm apache-activemq-5.6.0-bin.tar.gz
```

Edit conf/activemq.xml to accept ssl

```
gedit apache-activemq-5.6.0/conf/activemq.xml
```

replace the transportConnectors entry with the following lines (to enable SSL)

```
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="ssl"     uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61616?needClientAuth=true"/>
        </transportConnectors>
        <sslContext>
            <sslContext 
            keyStore="broker.ks" keyStorePassword="password"
            trustStore="client.ks" trustStorePassword="password"/>
        </sslContext>
```

start server

```
cd apache-activemq-5.6.0
bin/activemq start
```

view logging output

```
tail -f data/activemq.log
```

open another console then cd into the **testing-AMQ-Netlib-SSL** directory

Download latest SilverTunnel netlib into the testing directory

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/silvertunnel/files/silvertunnel_Netlib/silvertunnel.org_netlib-0.14-beta.zip
unzip silvertunnel.org_netlib-0.14-beta.zip
rm silvertunnel.org_netlib-0.14-beta.zip
```

compile the source code into three runnable jar files in separate directories

```
ant
```

run the consumer

```
cd consumer
./consumer
```

open another console then cd into the **testing-AMQ-Netlib-SSL/producer** directory

run the producer

```
./producer
```

let it run for a bit to satisfy yourself that it works then kill the producer by hitting ctrl+C

run the producer-tcpip

```
cd ../producer-tcpip
./producer-tcpip
```

let it run for a bit to satisfy yourself that it has stalled at a NullPointerException then kill the producer-tcpip by hitting ctrl+C

notice the debug message in producer-tcpip's output

```
tail -f logs/output.log
```

also notice the error message that appears at the bottom of activemq.log (see the tail output from the first console window) or type at the current prompt

```
tail -f ../apache-activemq-5.6.0/data/activemq.log
```

## Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know if it is important, but one major difference between the way that ActiveMQ and HornetQ implement SSL is that ActiveMQ requires some configuration via JVM command line options. For example a typical command line is: **java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=../apache-activemq-5.6.0/conf/client.ks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=../apache-activemq-5.6.0/conf/client.ts -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -jar  producer.jar** Could it be that when the JVM is TORified by Netlib that this information is lost or corrupted? Just a thought...

Comment: No, that idea in the previous comment isn't correct. I just successfully connected two Java applications via an SSLSocket (over Netlib). SSLSockets use the same command line configuration shown above. So the SSL command line parameters are handled okay by Netlib.

Comment: WORKAROUND: Using SSLSockets suggests a workaround for the incompatibility between Netlib and ActiveMQ. Rather than try to connect directly to ActiveMQ over a TORified SSL connection, instead connect to a small Java application (called 'receiver') on the server side via a TORified SSLSocket. Then on the server side the receiver program passes the data to the ActiveMQ server over a localhost TCP connection. Using an intermediary application means that Netlib and ActiveMQ don't have to come into direct contact.